# Which of these SQL Queries is Correct?

Tags: netezza

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have a table ("my_table") that contains information on:

- student_id (e.g. 123, 124,etc.)
- scholarship (1 = yes, 0 = no) : note that a student can receive a scholarship one year and lose it the next year (and vice versa) - but within the same year, a student can not change their scholarship status
- year_parking_ticket_recieved (multiple parking tickets can be received by the same student in the same year)
- year_parking_ticket_paid (the year in which a ticket is paid must always be greater than or equal to the year in which the ticket was received)

The table looks like this:

```
 student_id scholarship year_parking_ticket_received year_parking_ticket_paid
1          1           1                         2010                     2015
2          1           1                         2011                     2015
3          1           0                         2012                     2016
4          1           1                         2012                     2016
5          2           0                         2020                     2023
6          2           0                         2021                     2023
7          2           0                         2018                     2023
8          2           0                         2017                     2023
```

**I am trying to create a summary that shows how many students (scholarship = 1 vs scholarship = 0) paid exactly how many parking tickets per year (i.e. year_paid).** As an example:

- In 2010, 23 distinct students with scholarships each paid exactly 1 ticket
- In 2010, 13 distinct students with scholarships each paid exactly 2 tickets
- In 2011, 19 distinct students without scholarships each paid exactly 4 tickets
- etc.

The final result would look something like this:

```
  scholarship year_paid number_of_parking_tickets number_of_students_that_paid_exactly_this_number_of_tickets
1           1      2010                         1                                                          23
2           1      2010                         2                                                          14
3           1      2011                         3                                                          19
4           0      2010                         1                                                          20
```

**My Question:** A friend and I have been trying to figure out which is the correct way to solve this problem.

Here is my approach:

```
with cte as
(select student_id,
year_parking_ticket_paid, scholarship,
count(distinct year_parking_ticket_received) as distinct_year
from my_table
group by student_id, year_parking_ticket_paid,  scholarship),
cte2 as (
select year_parking_ticket_paid, distinct_year, sum(distinct_year) as count_distinct_year, scholarship
from cte
group by year_parking_ticket_paid, distinct_year, scholarship)
select * from cte2
```

And here is my friend's approach:

```
select year_parking_ticket_paid, number_of_parking_tickets, count(*)
from
(
select student_id, year_parking_ticket_paid, sum(scholarship) as schol, count(*) as number_of_parking_tickets
from my_table
group by student_id, year_parking_ticket_paid
) as a
group by year_parking_ticket_paid, number_of_parking_tickets
```

**We are both confused to which approach is the correct way to solve this problem - can someone please help us out?**

Thanks!

- Note: If Student 123 paid 4 tickets in 2010 ... he would not contribute to the rows for 2010 & 1 ticket, 2010 & 2 tickets, 2010 & 3 tickets ... he would only contribute to the row for 2010 & 4 tickets